# How to increase timeout of Amplify Nextjs SSR function from 10s to 30s?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I'm using a Next.js project on AWS Amplify. On my local environment, **one** of my API routes averages around **18-20 seconds** to finish as it makes multiple (6 total) third-party API requests to services outside of AWS. However, When deploying to Amplify, the API route gets timed-out at **10 seconds**.

I've tried manually setting the Amplify Lambda function to **30 seconds**, *this works* BUT it gets overwritten back to 10 seconds after every deployment. (see screenshot below)

###### CloudWatch log:

```
...

END RequestId: 0f5be97f-9519-4d07-8c51-45ec9968171f

REPORT RequestId: 0f5be97f-9519-4d07-8c51-45ec9968171f  Duration: 10010.52 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 159 MB 

2021-08-27T16:22:55.214Z 0f5be97f-9519-4d07-8c51-45ec9968171f Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

[image: aws amplify lambda function config]

Comment: Exactly!
Same problem here! :(

It's so sad when you find in stackoverflow exactly what you are looking for...and no one has an answer for it!

Comment: @FelipeNMoura Glad I'm not the only one facing this issue. I've come up with a temporary workaround of manually updating the timeout from 10s to 30s and deploying to Lambda@Edge. Gotta do this on EVERY amplify deployment tho :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they (AWS team) have fixed it!

Now, it keeps track of the timeout you had previously saved \o/